# How to create storage folder and sub folder using input names in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, upload, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

i am need advice to create folder upload in storage, i want to make folder using 4 column textbox

- Division
- activity
- year
- sponsor

how to make folder like this

```
storage/app/division/year/activity/sponsor/file.txt
```

and the code here

```
storage::disk('local')->put('logic');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you have sanitized and stored the input strings in the relative variables, to create the folder and upload the file you can do:

```
Storage::disk('local')
    ->put( $division .'/'. $activity . '/' . $year . '/' . $sponsor . '/file.txt',
           File::get( <your_file> )
);
```

Comment: great advice, let me try